# Remove everything from string but spaces, dashes and letters in R?

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to remove everything in a string except spaces dashes(-) and letters.
For example

`string1 <- "test-%432string *#$ one!~+"`

how do I return "test-string one"

I tried :
`gsub("[^a-zA-Z-\s]", "", string1)`
to no avail -- it removes the space, which should be left.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
/[^\w\-\s]|\d/
```

That worked for me. You can try it out on rubular.com.
Enjoy.

Or in R form:

```
gsub("[^\\w\\-\\s]|\\d","",string1,perl = TRUE)
[1] "test-string  one"
```

Comment: Close. This is actually not a valid regex in the R language, which requires that you double up the \. Also, this works in `gsub` only if you specify the argument `perl = TRUE`.

Comment: thanks to both of you, I also fiddled about with str_replace using the POSIX `[:space:]`, this aslo worked.